# Sound Issue with Nao Robot

Tags: nao-robot

I am having some issues with my Nao Robot (v5, naoqi 2.1.4), all the activities work without issue but after 20-30 minutes of the robot being turned on it starts making some strange noises and it won't stop until it is shut down.

I have done a factory reset using NaoFlasher but the same issue persists, does anyone have an idea of what might be the problem?

[Short video of the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JPcKJlyXft0)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my NAO Robot, 6 thousand pound and they don't work!

If you turn it upside down and hold the middle button for 60-90 seconds and complete the factory reset this should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's the same issue, we have a NAO robot in our development hub at work, it became unresponsive and would make piano noises?? - I think they solved it by saying "Robot Reset" to it several times, Worth a shot as it is currently operational.